# HTML/CSS popup display text from a list

Tags: python, html, css, popup, folium

Is it possible to use inside popup method a specific item from a pandas data frame (or a list)?

for example instead of writing:

```
popup = '<strong>Item</strong>'
```

to write
to do automatically this precedure instead of writing 100 popups?

`popup = df.iloc[i,1]'`

```
for i in range(100):
    folium.Marker([df.iloc[i,2], df.iloc[i,3]], popup = '<strong> Location</strong>', 
                  tooltip = tooltip, icon = folium.Icon(icon = 'cloud')).add_to(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Without modifying your code too much

```
for i in range(100):
    folium.Marker([df.iloc[i,2], df.iloc[i,3]], 
                  popup='<strong> {}</strong>'.format(df.iloc[i,1]), 
                  tooltip = tooltip, icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud')).add_to(m)
```

but consider a couple of other popular methods for plotting things in a dataframe.

First using [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row['your_lat_col'], row['your_long_col'], 
                  popup='<strong> {}</strong>'.format(row['your_popup_col']), 
                  tooltip = tooltip, icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud')).add_to(m)
```

Note:[itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) is not as popular but faster and very similar.  Your column names can't have spaces when using itertuples though.

Also, Python's zip() makes the iteration easy on the eyes

```
for lat, lon, popup in zip(df['your_lat_col'], df['your_long_col'], df['your_popup_col']):
        folium.Marker([lat, lon, popup='<strong> {}</strong>'.format(popup), 
                      tooltip = tooltip, icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud')).add_to(m)
```